# Connection to remote mysql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection, connection-string, access-denied

I'm trying to connect to MySQL database but I keep getting this error

```
 Authentication to host 'hostname' for user 'database' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'user'@'5.41.159.197' (using password: YES)
```

I'm very positive that my username and password are correct and also I granted all privileges to my user, what can be causing this? I uploaded my database to hostgator
This is my connection string:

```
        string connectionString = "server=serverNAme;port=3306 ; UID=username; password=password; database=database";
```

Am I missing something?

I was able to access the databases without any issues through php code for my other projects but now with the c# project I can't ! So, there must be something wrong with the connection string or with my code!

Comment: Is this an ASP application or a desktop one?

Comment: If you are accessing mysql directly from a machine that isn't the web server, there may be some sort of access control list that is blocking you. i.e. the access control list may be set up to allow the web server to talk to mysql, but not other machines.  So check to see if an access control list is involved.

Comment: @RonBeyer it's a desktop application

Comment: Glad that helped.  I think that was where @RonBeyer's question was headed, too.